# iOS error in substraction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have noticed a strange thing in Objective-C substraction:

I have a defined navigation bar height:

```
#define NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20.0f
```

Also I have a simple subtraction:

```
NSLog(@"%f - %f = %f", self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height, NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height - NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT);
```

Console output for this call:

```
768.000000 - 64.000000 = 744.000000
```

What the hell is wrong with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, **always** use brackets for `#define`

```
#define NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT (self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 20.0f)
```

Comment: Please, **never** use a macro, where you can use a method or function. ;-)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad : I prefer macro in this case as to access method/ function I have to write many lines instead of 1 keyword...

Comment: You remove comments like a developer … Arrogant

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad : LOL!!! Not me... Moderators removed it... Now you got who is what? :D :P

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad : Bro, lets not fight... You will do what you feel right... I will still go ahead with MACRO.. Enjoy coding...

Answer (score 0):

Change your line to,

```
 NSLog(@"%f - %f = %f", self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height, NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT, self.parentViewController.view.frame.size.height - (NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT));
```

Put `NAVIGATION_BAR_HEIGHT` in braces ( ).

Comment: I never see such case... Just curious why?

Comment: @FahimParkar you already have too much of experience, freshers usually do that ;)

Comment: @RoNiT : Naah.. iPhone just 2.5 years.. But I feel B.S is right... I faced issue like that before...